# Передача данных между формами с extern Windows Forms C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, консоль

Нужно передать данные между формами (не должны включать друг друга). Буду называть ту, из которой нужно передать главной. Windows Forms C++/CLI
Пробовал делать с помощью extern переменных, объявляя в главной как string str например, а в ту, в которой нужно получить - extern string str (если объявить наоборот или extern в обоих случаях то появляется ошибки линковки). Но тогда конструктор не хочет открываться и полностью очищает форму. Если пробовать объявить в главной форме

```
public ref class GlobalVariables abstract sealed
{
public:
    static array<double>^ globalArray;
};
```

То из дочерней не получится получить, пишет, что не объявлен GlobalVariables и globalArray.

Comment: Естественно необходимо включать заголовочный файл с объявлением другой формы.

Comment: Отложите на время WinForms. У вас не хватает базовых знаний. Узнайте, для чего нужны файлы .h и .cpp. Уясните, что куда нужно подключать. Потом вернитесь к формам и прокляните дизайнер, который сгенерированный код пишет в .h. Перенесите код в .cpp, оставив в заголовочном файле только объявления методов.

Comment: Проблема была скорее в том, что не линковалось потому что я привык писать код в .h вместо .cpp, в итоге помогло просто создать пространство имен в .h и .cpp и там уже описать все что нужно.